# Как изменит allert THANK YOU в форме Обратный связи

Tags: javascript, html

хочу поставить вместо allerta свой class или popup? как это реализовать?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Кастомизировать alert нельзя, выход - это пилить свою модалку

Comment: как это реализовать? свою модлалку *?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default
вот например, почитайте

Comment: Если используется jquery, как вариант - https://sweetalert2.github.io